# Connection refused when trying to control remotely

Tags: vnc

I've a Raspberry Pi B+ and I've set the autostart file to run VNC after boot.

I connect the USB Dongle and it works perfectly. It connects to the Wi-Fi automatically (with previous set of network SSID and pass key).
I used to control my Raspberry using VNC Viewer in Windows 8.1 and a hotspot Wi-Fi from my laptop and no problems were found.

I replaced the hotspot network, of my laptop, with an access point in order to connect the laptop and the Pi.

My problem is that VNC Viewer stops working and gives an error

> connection refused : 10061

although the IP is correct and I ensured that it's true by using `ping`.

Why was it connected by the hotspot network but not when using the access point? Why does VNC stop when the two devices join the same network?

Answer (score -1):

I have fixed my problem ... by stop power management ... it has disconnecting raspberry pi

> Make a file 8192cu.conf in directory /etc/modprobe.d/ with the command

```
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/8192cu.conf
```

and add the following lines

```
# Disable power management
options 8192cu rtw_power_mgnt=0 rtw_enusbss=0
```

thanks for everyone